# Issue with testing Class methods in Pytest

Tags: python, class, visual-studio-code, methods, pytest

I am trying to run a test in one folder (folder A) calling a class made in a different folder (folder B), but both folders (A and B) are located in the same directory.
And when I run the test file, it is giving me import errors of the class created in the folder B.

Error in Gitbash:

[![][1]][1]

And you can see the directory flow

Path directory in VSCode:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `testing` folder is not in the `PYTHONPATH`.

You can add your workspace folder(testing) into the `PYTHONPATH` through add this in the settings.json:

```
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder};"
  },
```

And then you can import `accum.py` from `stuff` package directly: `from stuff import accum`.